# TypeError: (0 , _umi.connect) is not a function while using jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest and enzyme for unit testing. But instead of react-redux, I am using umi for centralised state management but yeah behind the scenes it uses redux only. Now when I run test files I am getting this error

TypeError: (0 , _umi.connect) is not a function

```
  101 | };
  102 | 
> 103 | export default connect(({ login, loading }: ConnectState) => ({
      |                ^
  104 |   userLogin: login,
  105 |   submitting: loading.effects['login/login'],
  106 | }))(Login);

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/user/login/index.tsx:103:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/user/login/login.test.js:6:1)
```

Here is my test file

```
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Login component tests', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(
    <LoginContainer.WrappedComponent userLogin={{ status: '', message: '' }} />,
  );
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is an already opened github issue. The problem is basically with the umi library. I used connect method of react-redux and it worked fine but at the same time, it's not appropriate to have one more library just to use the connect method. I am using it till it get's fixed in umi.

https://github.com/umijs/umi/issues/5138
and
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/6401